# Answer form does not disappear when someone dupehammers the question and edits it

Tags: bug, dupehammer

> [image: boo]

When you open a question and someone with a gold tag badge (or a diamond) dupehammers it AND edits it, click "this post has been edited" and the question will refresh, but the answer form remains.

Comment: Does the UI still allow you to post an answer? (I know the server will allow it, as it doesn't block answers until 4 hours later.)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Of course it submits an answer.

Comment: What I mean is, it doesn't show, "this question has been closed; no new answers are being accepted" and disable the button?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I guess no (within 4 hours).

Comment: But when you reload, all is good, right?

Comment: Doesn't closing a question and then editing it push it to the reopen queue?

Comment: @brasofilo Does pushing to the reopen queue enable answering?

Comment: Not sure, but closing then editing is doing it wrong.